# Unity LineRenderer.GetPositions not working as intended

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When trying to retrieve all positions from a line renderer by using the GetPositions method I am running into a problem.
The [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.GetPositions.html) states, that the function can be used by passing a Vector3 array as an out parameter but it won't let me do that.
Below is an excerpt of my code.
It gives me the error "Argument 'pos' should not be passed with the 'out' keyword" at line 3

```cs
LineRenderer lineRenderer = this.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
Vector3[] pos = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
int test = lineRenderer.GetPositions(out pos);
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of your link is for Unity version **2020**. The `out` parameter was added in **2018**.

You seem to be using an older version where the `out` was not there yet e.g. [2017](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.4/Documentation/ScriptReference/LineRenderer.GetPositions.html) where there was no `out` parameter yet.

Always make sure to use the correct API version according to the Unity version you are using for your project ;)

---

Hm just looked into the source code and since even the [`LineRendererEditor`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Editor/Mono/Inspector/LineRendererEditor.cs#L379) uses it without `out` it seems to be a mistake in the documentation?!

Left a comment there so maybe it gets updated soon.

Comment: i have unity 2020 and it gives me the same error

Comment: @FreeLearning hm strange, currently not on a PC but see update at the bottom ... it seems to be a mistake in the documentation (?) since a source code of the `LineRendererEditor` from UnityTechnologies itself is actually using it without `out` as well ...

Comment: Yes, it seems an error, as I wrote below my answer even if you hover over it with the mouse (at the function) (where it tells you the type of variable you have to insert in the method), it does not write any "out"

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the word "out" it will work

Comment: As for the documentation I have seen that there is the word "out", but it doesn't seem to work. If you hover over "GetPositions" (in the script) it does not ask for the word "out". Could this be a mistake in the documentation? (or it means that the parameter you enter is returned a value (even if it seems to me to be a bit confusing))? Or I missing something.